# what is the best approach to migrate on-prem mssql/stored-procs(a lot)/C# app to AWS environment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-aurora

We are planning to migrate/rebuild an app which utilizes on-prem MSSQL server, lots of stored procs. And apps are written in .Net (not .Net core)

The idea is to migrate the app into AWS maximizing cloud technology (no EC2). We will use Lambda and convert it to serverless. 
But for DB side, I'm not sure which is the better approach. Ideally RDS MSSQL but looks like that comes with lots of limitation such as no support of replication. If we go to Aurora, data migration from MSSql to Aurora would require a lot of times plus Stored Procs that are used won't be able to re-use.

any idea?

try to minimize drastic changes as there is a tight time limit.

Comment: What sort of replication are you looking to achieve on RDC?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this. But you might need to looks at [DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)

and [AWS ACT](http://AWS%20Schema%20Conversion%20Tool)

Also, there is a [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-your-procedural-sql-code-with-the-aws-schema-conversion-tool/) on something similar

Replication is there with aurora, you would have a read replicas